# Are constexprs stored in .rodata section

Tags: c++

I read [c++11 faq](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#constexpr) and find this sentence:

> Typically we want the compile-time evaluation guarantee for **global or namespace objects**, often for objects we want to place in read-only storage.

I want to see how my compiler(gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) ) does, so I write code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
constexpr int add5(int i){ 
        return i+5;    
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
constexpr int read_only = add5(10);
cout << &read_only <<endl;
return 0;  
}
```

I thought that `read-only` will appeared in .rodata section but it didn't show up. Apparently people may think that the compiler do optimization. In this view, I thought that almost every constant expression can be store in the table of compiler but not omitted into target code. If there exit some constant expression should exist in target code in read-only storage for better occasion.

```
~$: ./constexpr 
0x7fff622addec
~$: cat /proc/3051/maps 
7fff6228e000-7fff622af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I don't understand well the sentence I quote specifically the **bold** part.
As the comment below,`read_only` is a local variable which will appear in stack as result above.
It's meaningless if we don't talk about the global data or in namespace:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
constexpr int add5(int i){
        return i+5;
}
constexpr int read_only = add5(10);
int global_int = add5(10);
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
cout << &read_only <<endl;
cout << &global_int <<endl;
getchar();
return 0;
}


~$: ./constexpr 
0x4009b8
0x601068
~$: cat /proc/3157/maps 
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 1200603              /home/shia/constexpr
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:09 1200603              /home/shia/constexpr
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:09 1200603              /home/shia/constexpr
```

It worked as I expected.And about the global variable declared with prefix `const` :

> A variable or data member declared with constexpr behaves as if it was
>   declared with const, except that it requires initialization before use
>   and its initializer must be a constant-expression. Therefore a
>   constexpr variable can always be used as part of a constant expression

So,it should also appear in `.rodata` section.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just optimize it away *because you don't use it*? Try to put in a `std::cout << read_only << '\n';` (though even that could be just turned into a simple `std::cout << 15 << '\n';`, so maybe rather `std::cout << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&read_only) << '\n';` to force him make it an actual memory location). And what are the compiler flags?

Comment: And for the future, in English it's common practice to put a space after punctuation marks.

Comment: @ChristianRau The compiler flags `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. It doesn't work using reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @yuan "it doesn't work" is not useful.  Does it make your computer explode?  Output an error message and fail to compile?

Comment: I can just find the read_only symbol using `objdump -j --demangle -s .rodata ExcutableFileName`

Comment: `read_only` is a local variable, so it will never appear in the `objdump` output, as it has no linkage. Try an external global variable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared a local variable. If the function were recursive or the program were multithreaded, you could have two of them at the same time. Two different objects can't have the same address, because the definition of an object in C++ is a thing with a unique address.

As already noted, there is no guarantee that a `constexpr` variable initialization will not be evaluated at runtime. The compiler is allowed to use read-write memory and call `add5` even for the global variable. In this case, though, that's irrelevant. It needs to place the local variable there to do a dance so it can have a proper address.

Moreover, you (the user) are not allowed to see the difference between a program which does initialization at runtime and one with compile-time-only evaluation, aside from performance. Any experiment to discern it is bound to default back to runtime evaluation behavior.

If you don't take its address, the requirement ceases to apply. It can then disappear from the stack, and from runtime operations entirely.

Comment: As comment above under the question,I add `&` to let compiler don't omit constant expression using in compiler which is common to be done.

Comment: @yuan That doesn't make sense grammatically. By the way, "omit" means "to leave out or forget" whereas "emit", which you may be looking for, means "to make or generate."

Comment: I want using `&` to let compiler generate or make the constant expression not leave out.

Comment: @yuan Still not clear on your intent. `&` is taking the address, and you're not taking the address of the expression, you're taking the address of the variable, which is on the stack. Hence you are asking the compiler for an address on the stack. A `constexpr` (or indeed, any kind of variable) need not be stored anywhere if its address is never taken.

Comment: A `constexpr` in global or namespace ,when I address it,it should store in `.rodata` as expected,In such circumstance,it shouldn't be leave out by compiler?No about the scoped variable.

Comment: @yuan Anything you put the `&` operator on will have an address, and anything with an address can't be "left out," as the memory at that address must have the required values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31436/discussion-between-yuan-and-potatoswatter)

Answer (score 0):

The way I read it, `constexpr` guarantees that it *can* be evaluated at compile-time, but it is not necessarily even evaluated at all.

It does not, however, guarantee that it will be evaluated at all if not needed (i.e. optimized away as in your case).

E.g. (from your link):

> [...] they are basically values kept in the compiler's tables and only emitted into the generated code *if needed*

Comment: I hard configure when need emitted into generated code,what do you think?

Comment: -1, a `constexpr` object is required to have a value that *can* be determined at compile time, but there is no guarantee anywhere that the compiler will actually do that, except in a context where the value is required at compile time, such as a template argument.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That is what I meant, but I realize that I did not express myself very well. Thank you for pointing out. Answer updated.